# How to make a DIV not breakable with CSS in printable page?

Tags: html, css

I have some div containers that have some content  inside them, when they reach a specific height the break to a new column, here the content of the div are breaking so some content stay in column 1 and others content go to column 2 . I do not want that , I want all the content of the div go to the column 2.

It works normally on the html page but when I try to print it, it doesent work

`

```
.grade-table is the main containers 
.grade is the div I'm talking about
```

CSS

```
  .grade-table{
    margin-top: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-fill: auto;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .grade-table .grade{
  overflow: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Please post a complete example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.